# win32 DialogBox app: how to make the dialog box hidden on startup?

Tags: winapi, dialog

I have a win32 app which uses DialogBox() to display its main window.

I now want to start this app up with the dialog box invisible, and later set it visible with 
SetWindowPos(hDlg, HWND_TOPMOST, ...

Unfortunately

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645452(VS.85).aspx

> The function displays the dialog box (regardless of whether the template specifies the WS_VISIBLE style)

... it seems that there's no way of doing this using DialogBox().

I could add a call to 
SetWindowPos(hDlg, HWND_NOTOPMOST...

in my dialog procedure in the WM_INITDIALOG handler.

... but I'm concerned that under heavy system loading the dialog box will briefly appear then disappear, giving an ugly flicker effect.

Is there a way of creating my dialog box via DialogBox() without showing it?

Comment: Could you bypass DialogBox and just use CreateWindowEx, etc.?

Comment: @YWE: I'm not sure. MSDN says that DialogBox() uses CreateWindowEx() internally, so it ought to be possible. My dialog procedure expects messages such as WM_INITDIALOG, and makes dialog calls such as SendDlgItemMessage(): not sure whether all this will still work if I use CreateWindowEx().

Comment: I don't get the problem.  If you don't want the dialog to show then just don't call ShowDialog().  Pump your own message loop if necessary.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I want the dialog to be created, process messages, retain some state, then become visible if it needs to. As you suggest, I'll probably need to include a message loop. No big deal, but had hoped to avoid the extra lines of code.

Comment: I don't get that either.  Writing lines of code, isn't that what they pay you to do?  Go write.

Comment: I'm with Hans.  I don't get the problem.  Pump messages and call "DialogBox(...)" to show the dialog.

Comment: @Hans Passant: I tend towards the opinion that as a developer I'm paid to write as little code as possible, but no less. A simple solution with less code will be easier for other developers to maintain. But that's a very different discussion, and from people's comments here CreateWindowsEx() and a message pump seems likely to be  the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
ShowWindow(Hwnd, SW_HIDE);
```

i think it will work.

http://www.winprog.org/tutorial/modeless_dialogs.html

Answer (score 0):

I had some success with this technique

```
void CMyDlg::OnWindowPosChanging(WINDOWPOS* lpWndPos)
{
    // hide dialog
    lpWndPos->flags &= ~SWP_SHOWWINDOW;
    CDialog::OnWindowPosChanging(lpWndPos);
}
```

from [here](http://computer-programming-forum.com/82-mfc/621a651f62b4053d.htm)